# Which framework should I learn if I want to do web development in Java? Any advice?

Tags: java, web-development, asp.net

Well, I don't have a strong background in programming. I know C, C++, some C#, some vb, and some basic java and SQL, that's it. I don't have any work experience in web development, so just consider me as a completely new starter.

I would like to do web development, and I hope I can easily find a job in web development after I finish my current academic program. So I have started with asp.net MVC framework. But, at least it seems to me that many positions require java programming in web development, so I decide to learn java at the same time while learning .net. Well, there are a lot of frameworks out there. A friend of mine suggests Hibernate, some people say that play framework is good for small applications, whereas some guys recommend spring, which seems to be a very difficult one. I want to start with a framework which is relatively easy to pick up and popular in job market. So what should I start with? And aside from a framework, what else should I learn?

Besides, which one is more popular in terms of web programming, .net or Java? It seems that java is required by most employers, and I haven't found many positions indicating .net experience. Which of the two is actually more popular, and what about the trend in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking many questions in one question.

There are lots of jobs for Java developers and .Net Developers. With experience and hard working you will be able to handle C# and Java both ecosystems are similar.

But first you need to settle in one. I suggest you keep using C# and Asp.Net MVC, Its a very nice stack with incredible potential and features.

If you really want to dig into Java ecosystem, I recommend Spring MVC with Spring Core, Spring Data and JPA2/Hibernate. For template FreeMarker is easy and fast.

- Spring MVC is the View and Controller based on MVC pattern
- Spring Core is used for DI and services
- Spring Data JPA gives you the repository pattern and level of abstration from the models
- JPA2/Hibernate for your models

Try to use Maven for all dependencies and this stack will give you everything for create powerful Java web applications.

About popularity on Dice.com Java is more popular than C# but I found more jobs as C# Web Developer than Java Web Developer but all depends.

Learn the tools you like most and really it does not matter, I was a Java developer and I got picked for a C# contract lately, I didn't not have deep knowledge in the tools but the import is your experience and that you are a fast learned and can pick up any tool right away.

Comment: Q was closed when I was almost finished. I agree with pretty much everything you write, except for Spring - I would not ever recommend that for a beginner.